# I want to update data but it show me a InvaildCastException

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have Classess:Person,Student,Teacher

Person Class Is:

```
public class Person
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string email;

    public Person()
    {
    }
    public int CompareTo(Person b)
    {

        return this.Email.CompareTo(b.Email);
    }

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, string email)
    {
        this.Firstname = firstname;
        this.Lastname = lastname;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public string Firstname{get;set;}       
    public string Lastname{get;set;}
    public string Email{get;set;}


    public virtual string  GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return Firstname + sep + Lastname + sep + Email;
    }

}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Students : Person
{
    private double assessmentGrade;
    private double assignmentGrade;

    public Students()
    {
    }

    public Students(string firstname, string lastname, 
                    double assessmentGrade,double assignmentGrade,
                    string email) : base(firstname, lastname, email)
    {
        this.AssessmentGrade = assessmentGrade;
        this.AssignmentGrade = assignmentGrade;
    }

    public double AssignmentGrade{get;set;}
    public double AssessmentGrade{get;set;}

    public override string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return base.GetDisplayText(sep) + "   " + 
               AssessmentGrade + "   " + AssignmentGrade;
    }

}
```

Teacher Class:

```
public class Teacher : Person
{
    private int roomNumber;

    public Teacher()
    {
    }

    public Teacher(string firstname, string lastname, int roomNumber,
        string email) : base(firstname, lastname, email)
    {
        this.RoomNumber = roomNumber;
    }

    public int RoomNumber{get;set;}
     public override string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return base.GetDisplayText(sep) + " , RoomNo " + RoomNumber;
    }

}
```

I have one more PersonList Class:

```
public class PersonList : List<Person>
{
    List<Person> person = new List<Person>();

    public delegate void ChangeHandler(PersonList persons);
    public event ChangeHandler Changed;

    public bool Contains(string email)
    {
        return this[email] != null;
    }

    public new void Add(Person p)
    {
        base.Insert(0, p);
    }

    // Provide two additional methods
    public void Fill()
    {
        List<Person> persons = PersonDB.GetPersons();
        foreach (Person person in persons)
            base.Add(person);
    }

    public void remove(Person persons)
    {
        person.Remove(persons);
    }

    public static PersonList operator +(PersonList persons, Person p)
    {
        persons.Add(p);
        return persons;

    }
    public static PersonList operator -(PersonList persons, Person p)
    {
        persons.remove(p);
        return persons;
    }

    public void Save()
    {

        PersonDB.SavePersons(this);
    }
}
```

Now I am tring to upload the data from Form2:

```
private PersonList persons = new PersonList();

             private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Form2 update = new Form2();
        Person updteDtl = (Person)lstPerson.SelectedItem;

        if (lstPerson.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < persons.Count; j++)
            {
                if (persons[j] == updteDtl)
                {
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            update.UpdatingData = updteDtl;
            Person updatePerson = update.GetNewPerson();

            if (updatePerson != null)
            {
                persons[i] = updatePerson;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select the person to update.");
        }

    }
```

On Form2 I am trying to upload the data.

```
private Person person = null;

    public Person GetNewPerson()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
        return person;
    }
         private Person updatingData = new Person();
    public Person UpdatingData
    {
        set { updatingData = value; }
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (updatingData is Students)
        {
            Students std = (Students)updatingData;

            txtName.Text =  std.Firstname;
            txtLName.Text = std.Lastname;
            txtEmail.Text = std.Email;
            txtAssessGrade.Text = std.AssessmentGrade.ToString();
            txtAssigGrade.Text = std.AssignmentGrade.ToString();
        }
        else if (updatingData is Teacher)
        {
            rbTeacher.Checked = true;
            Teacher teacher = (Teacher)updatingData;

            txtName.Text = teacher.Firstname;
            txtLName.Text = teacher.Lastname;
            txtEmail.Text = teacher.Email;
            txtAssessGrade.Text = teacher.RoomNumber.ToString();

        }                     
    }
```

I want to retrieve the data from Form2 which i select in listbox and update that data
But When i run this and click the update button then it show me a error **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'ProductMaint.Person'.** Please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: There is a lot of code here but not much information on how the ListBox is being populated or which line throws the exception.

Comment: It's probably happening at this line: `Person updteDtl = (Person)lstPerson.SelectedItem;`. Does your listbox contain `Person` objects or strings?

Comment: A lot of the skill in programming is working out which parts of a code base are relevant when diagnosing a problem. It's *particularly* important when posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes inthe listbox shows Firstname,Lastname,Email,AssignmentGrade,Assessment Grade,Room number

Answer (score 1):

I assume this line is the one throwing the exception:

```
Person updteDtl = (Person)lstPerson.SelectedItem;
```

In other words, the selected item in `lstPerson` is a string, not a `Person`, so you can't cast it to a `Person`.

Unfortunately, despite the fact that you've shown us hundreds of lines of code, you haven't told us about `lstPerson` or why you *expect* `lstPerson.SelectedItem` to be a `Person`. (You haven't even told us what kind of app you're writing.)

That's the cause of your problems, and it has very little to do with the code you've posted - so focus on that part. Either change how you're binding to the list, or work out a way of getting the relevant person based on whichever string is in `SelectedItem`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem stems from this line:

```
Person updteDtl = (Person)lstPerson.SelectedItem;
```

Apparently this returns a String, and not a `Person` object. I'm not actually sure if it is possible to store an object such as an instance of `Person` in a dropdown list (I assume that is what `lstPerson` is?).

A solution could be to use one of the fields to identify each person, and use that as the value of the items in the dropdown (e-mail, for example, will probably be unique for each person? Otherwise, add a new field `PersonId` for just this purpose). As each item in a dropdown list can have both a `value` field and a text string to display, you could use the ID as the value, and the name (or whatever you want) for the display text.

In the event handler, you will then have to get the `value`, and use that to look up the person in your `Person` list. You can then update that person with the rest of the data from the form.

I hope I understood your question correctly, and that this is clear enough to be of some help, good luck!